# my route in codeigniter does not work for dynamic pages

Tags: codeigniter

**my page url is**
http://example.com/ci/pages/portofolio

**My roots in config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'display/display_pages/$1'; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**My controller in controllers/display.php**

```
class display extends MY_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    public function display_pages($seo_name){
        echo $seo_name; 
    }

}
```

**i receive this message**

Not Found

The requested URL /ci/pages/portofolio was not found on this server.

Comment: your base url is   http://example.com/ci/  .??

Comment: This is my base url in ci\system\core\Config.php
$base_url = 'http://example.com/ci';

Comment: any other suggestion plz

Comment: did you try with `$route['display/(:any)'] ='display/display_pages/$1'; ` initially?

Comment: my pages accessed by this url but i need url that i have put in question :
http://localhost/ci/index.php/display/display_pages/about

Comment: Yes i try it
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'display/display_pages/$1';

Comment: try with `Display` as class name instead of `display`

Comment: Try with Display but no luck

Comment: Do you have any htaccess in your project?

Comment: route['pages/(:any)'] = 'display/display_pages/$1'; 
Your route specifies pages/(:any) as leading to that path, I don't see display/(:any) in your config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `$1` at the end of your route. Make it look like this :

```
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'display/display_pages';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route.php is correct. The way you are printing the $seo_name is not.

```
public function display_pages(){
    echo $this->uri->segment(3); // it will print $1
}
```

Check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

The htaccess should be something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```